# Can I Configure a Majority and File Share Quorum Where the File Share is Accessed Over the Internet?

Tags: windows-cluster

I have a 2-site geographically dispersed Cluster setup and have 1 node in each site. Both sites are connected with FC for large volume synchronous data replication and high-bandwidth network availability.

As I understand the best quorum configuration for this setup is Majority and File Share Quorum, and the File Share must reside in a 3rd site. Can file share be on a hosted machine in a remote site with a reliable private connection?

Comment: what os level are you running I assume w2k8r2 is that correct?

Comment: yes, I'm running w2k8r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is w2k8r2 the the following is a good link, its for sql but applies to clustering in general.

http://clusteringformeremortals.com/2009/09/15/step-by-step-configuring-a-2-node-multi-site-cluster-on-windows-server-2008-r2-%e2%80%93-part-1/

Comment: The answer actually lies in part 1 of this blog, but it answered it well enough for what I needed.
I'd be happy if you could edit your answer to contain a link to the first part, and in it the part about network considerations, and then I'll remove this comment asking you you to do so.